# Custom Report Generation -VF Salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, email, custom-report-type

I have a requirement where I need to create a custom VF report which will be created automatically every month and will be sent to the respective client along with email template.

Though I have not started working on this but I am clear with how to create my report.

I have doubt regarding automatic report generation every month?
How can I automatically generate the reports every month?
How can I keep track of all the reports generated every month?

I do need to send those reports to the client along with email template.

Answer (score 2):

you can use apex scheduler where you can specify date and time to execute code. Please follow below link. I used the same for sending reports via mail on dialy basis.

[Apex Scheduler](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm)

```
global class TestScheduledApexFromTestMethod implements Schedulable {
// This test runs a scheduled job at midnight Sept. 3rd. 2022

public static String CRON_EXP = '0 0 0 3 9 ? 2022';

global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
  CronTrigger ct = [SELECT Id, CronExpression, TimesTriggered, NextFireTime
            FROM CronTrigger WHERE Id = :ctx.getTriggerId()];

  System.assertEquals(CRON_EXP, ct.CronExpression);
  System.assertEquals(0, ct.TimesTriggered);
  System.assertEquals('2022-09-03 00:00:00', String.valueOf(ct.NextFireTime));

  Account a = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Name = 
              'testScheduledApexFromTestMethod'];
  a.name = 'testScheduledApexFromTestMethodUpdated';
  update a;
  }   
}
```

Comment: RAJ K, it's prefered that you at least include the relevant parts in your post. That way the answer actually contains the answer than reference it elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses.I have taken a different approach.I created a Vf page(render as PDF) along with a controller.I wrote a method in my controller which sends an email to the specified user along with the attachment(PDF).Then i wrote a scheduler class and called my class method in scheduler class.I scheduled the scheduler class to run on the last day of every month.Now i am stuck with saving the same PDF in Document folder. Any idea how to do this? Thank you All.